# How to use inline condition in Razor Pages that evaluates Razor tags

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have the following code in my razor page and it works fine.

```
<dd class="col-sm-6">
@if (Model.Status.Equals("inactive", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactName)
}
else
{
    <input asp-for="Model.ContactName" class="form-control" /><span asp-validation-for="Model.ContactName" class="text-danger"/>
}
```

I want to convert this to inline condition. How can I do that? I was trying the following, but it doesn't evaluate razor tags.

```
<dd class="col-sm-6">
@(Model.Status.Equals("inactive", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactName):Html.Raw(value: $"<input asp-for=\"{Model.ContactName}\" class=\"form-control\" /><span asp-validation-for=\"{Model.ContactName}\" class=\"text-danger\" />"))
```

Comment: Oh it is quite stupid but i think it will work since it was bothering me a lot... Regard not showing error or warning add `@` before `Html.DisplayFor`

Comment: Frankly I think inline conditionals should be for simple statements. It's more readable in your first version.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.Raw` is used to returns markup that is not HTML encoded.So it could not evaluate `asp-for` tag.You could only change like below then you could evaluate `asp-for`.Also it could not evaluate `asp-validation-for`:

```
@(Model.Status.Equals("inactive", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactName) : Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactName))
<span asp-validation-for="Model.ContactName" class="text-danger" />
```

I suggest that your first version would be better.

Reference: [HtmlHelper.Raw Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: Above doesn't work. Using 'if' statement produces <input class="form-control valid" type="text" id="CardViewModel_ContactName" name="CardViewModel.ContactName" value="Contact Name 4" aria-invalid="false">

Using inline condition like above produces this. It doesn't evaluate asp-for tag.
<input asp-for="Contact Name 4" class="form-control">

Comment: That is because `Html.Raw` just returns markup that is not HTML encoded.So in your case,I suggest that you could use your first version.If you really want to use  inline condition,please check my answer.